# Write a python program that finds all files with a given prefix and fill the gap

Tags: python

I am a beginner of python.  I have this task:

Write a program that finds all files with a given prefix, such as spam001.txt, spam002.txt, and so on, in a single folder and locates any gaps in the numbering (such as if there is a spam001.txt and spam003.txt but no spam002.txt). Have the program rename all the later files to close this gap.

I have written my code, and it seems to work, but it looks ugly, not elegant.  Especially the 3 if statements. How can I shorten it?

Here is my code:

```
# My main idea is to copy the file which is not in right order,
# and rename it, then delete it.

import os, re, shutil


# Arguments: folder, prefix
def fillGap(folder,prefix):


    # Create regex with prefix + number + extension.
    fileRegex = re.compile(r'(%s)((\d)(\d)(\d))\.txt' % prefix)

    # Makee sure the path is absolute.
    folder = os.path.abspath(folder)

    # When I commented the following one line, the program outptu is
    # FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   'spam004.txt'
    os.chdir(folder)  # This line is to avoid the FileNotFoundError.

    # Make a list to contain the file with prefix.
    fileNames = list()
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        if re.search(fileRegex, filename):
            fileNames.append(filename)
    # Make sure the fileName in the list have a right order.

    fileNames.sort()
    print(fileNames)
    # Find the gap through incremting loops
    for i in range(len(fileNames)):
        mo = re.search(fileRegex, fileNames[i])
        if int(mo.group(2)) == i + 1:
            continue
        # The group(2) has three digits, so it need to 3 Ifs.
        # Copy the old file and rename it then delete the old one.
        if i + 1 < 10:
            shutil.copy
            newFileName =prefix + '00' + str(i + 1) + '.txt'
            shutil.copy(fileNames[i], newFileName)
            os.unlink(fileNames[i])
        elif i + 1 < 100:
            shutil.copy(fileNames[i], prefix + '0' + str(i+1) + '.txt')
            os.unlink(fileNames[i])
        else:
            shutil.copy(fileNames[i], prefix + str(i+1) + '.txt')
            os.unlink(fileNames[i])

folder = '/home/jianjun/spam/'
prefix = 'spam'

fillGap(folder, prefix)
```

Comment: if the code works, but you want to improve it, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Peilonrayz There are a number of predefined close options for other sites.  It *is* off topic for SO and more on topic for codereview.  It does not matter if codereview takes it or not, the OP would have better luck there though.

Answer (score 4):

The regex is probably working but if you are looking for a common prefix then you might stick with the `str.startswith` function:

```
files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(folder) if filename.startswith('spam')]
```

Then to find the numbers you could just strip the prefix and the file extension away (not sure if this step is necessary, why would you need the old numbers?):

```
numbers = [int(filename.lstrip('spam').rstrip('.txt')) for filename in files]
```

To fill small numbers with leading zeros you might just use `{:0>3}.format`, for example see:

```
>>> '{:0>3}'.format(2)
002
```

so instead of using `prefix + str(i+1) + '.txt'` and variants this reduces to:

```
newfilenames = ['spam{:0>3}.txt'.format(number+1) for number in range(len(files))]
```

Assuming you `sort` your files before creating the numbers you now have a list of old names and new names that you can iterate over to rename them:

```
for oldname, newname in zip(files, newfilenames):
    shutil.copy(oldname, newname)
    os.unlink(oldname)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It looks more elegant.

Comment: @ShiJianjun No problem, I'm glad if it helps.

Comment: @ShiJianjun Feel free to accept or upvote the answer if it really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def gaps(dire, prefix):

    import os, re, shutil

    folder =  os.path.abspath(dire)
    sablon = re.compile(r'''(%s)(\d\d\d).txt''' % prefix)
    matchlist = []

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        match = sablon.match(filename)
        if match:
            matchlist.append(filename)
            if int(match.group(2)) == len(matchlist):
                continue
            else:
                print(filename + ' is the ' + str(len(matchlist)) + 'th file')
                if len(matchlist) < 9:
                    print(filename + ' will be renamed: ' + prefix + '00' + str(len(matchlist)) + '.txt')
                    newname = prefix + '00' + str(len(matchlist)) + '.txt'
                    oldname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
                    newname = os.path.join(folder, newname)
                    shutil.move(oldname, newname)

                elif 10 <= len(matchlist) < 100:
                    print(filename + ' will be renamed: ' + prefix + '0' + str(len(matchlist)) + '.txt')
                    newname = prefix + '0' + str(len(matchlist)) + '.txt'
                    oldname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
                    newname = os.path.join(folder, newname)
                    shutil.move(oldname, newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#?python3
#writing a program that takes folder path and a prefix of the folder name and identify gaps.
import os,shutil,re
def gaps(folder, prefix):
    folder = os.path.abspath(folder)
    os.chdir(folder)
    file_regex = re.compile(r'^%s00(\d).txt$'%prefix)
    number = 1
    for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            oldname = os.path.basename(file)
            match_obj = file_regex.search(file)
            no = match_obj.group(1)
            no = int(no)
            if no == number:
                number +=1
            else:
                no = number
                newname = prefix + "00" + str(no) + '.txt'
                print(f'Changing {oldname} to {newname}')
                shutil.move(oldname,newname)
gaps("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/randomfolder",'spam')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic and easy method to list all the files with a beginning prefix. Hope this helps!

```
import os

for path, currentDirectory, files in os.walk("/Users/pythonProject/spam_folder"):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("spam"):
            print(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a script i wrote for this exercise.
i hope it helps anyone

```
import os, re

directory = "c:\\users\\pt world\\documents"

os.chdir(directory)

regexObject = re.compile(r"^spam00(\d).txt$")

number = 1


for folder, subfolder, filename in os.walk(directory):
    for filenames in filename:
         matchObject = regexObject.search(filenames)
         if matchObject:
            if int(matchObject.group(1)) == number:
                number += 1

         else: 
            os.rename(matchObject.group(),\
            "spam00{}.txt".format(number))
                   number += 1
```

Comment: the code searches for the specific ```spam00(\d)``` regex, whilst the exercise says to search for any string with numbers in the prefix